# Create a BlogPost XWiki with REST

Tags: rest, blogs, xwiki

I need to create (with XWiki API REST) a BlogPost. But I don't know to use REST...
With this command :

```sh
$ curl -u Admin:admin -X PUT --data-binary "@newpage.xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main/pages/NewPage
```

and with this XML file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<page xmlns="http://www.xwiki.org">     
        <title>Hello world</title>
        <syntax>xwiki/2.0</syntax>
        <content>This is a new page</content>
</page>
```

I create a Page in the space `Main`. But I want a BlogPost in the space `Blog`. What's the markup that I must use? (I have found this command [here](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Features/XWikiRESTfulAPI#HSendingrepresentations))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command to use is:

```sh
curl -u Admin:admin -X POST --data-binary "@blogpost.xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Blog/pages/A+New+Blogpost/objects
```

The XML file should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<object xmlns="http://www.xwiki.org"><className>Blog.BlogPostClass</className>
    <property name="category"><value>Blog.News</value></property>
    <property name="content"><value>This is the new blog post. You can use **wiki syntax** in it.

Don't forget to escape XML entities like &amp; and &lt;!</value></property>
    <property name="publishDate"><value>2012-06-06 12:00:00.0</value></property>
    <property name="published"><value>1</value></property>
    <property name="title"><value>Second blog post</value></property>
</object>
```

A few things to note:

- The document must already exist, this doesn't work for a non-existing document. So, first thing to do is to `PUT` a title and parent into a new document, then you can add objects to it.
- The right verb for creating objects is `POST`, and the URL is obtained by appending `/objects` to the document's REST URL.
- The actual REST URL of the newly created object is returned as a redirect. You can either intercept the redirect and process the URL as you need, or you can let the redirect go through and you'll get back the object that was created with the verbose full syntax.
- In general, when sending resources the same syntax as the one returned when getting resources is used, although not all the data is needed. For instance, I obtained the XML for this object by first getting an existing blogpost object, then removing all that the server doesn't need to receive since it can compute it locally.
- One thing I noticed (and I consider a bug) is that when getting resources, XML entities are encoded twice (`&amp;#39;`), while sent resources should have entities encoded only once (`&#39;`).

Comment: Also see http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Features/XWikiRESTfulAPI#HCreatinganXWikiObject

Comment: it is possible to use cors?

Answer (score 0):

Generally with REST, you'd expect to send the PUT message to the URL that you wish to create (or update). Thus, you'd change from:

```
http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main/pages/NewPage
```

to maybe this (assuming you're creating `BlogPost` in the space `Blog`):

```
http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Blog/pages/BlogPost
```

The rest of the command should be whatever works for you. Since it's working now for creating a page in the Main space, I'd expect it to be enough.